# Isolated storage vs Application data folder

Tags: .net

Can some tell me differences between using isolated storage and Application Data Folder.

Which folder is recommended to use to store application specific local store.

Answer (score 4):

Isolated storage will give you a folder you can read from and write to without dealing with file and folder permissions.  That's always nice.  The thing is, though, accessing isolated storage isn't as easy as accessing a local folder.

That said, it depends on what you want to store.  App_Data is for data files (database files, etc.).  If that's what you need to store, then by all means, use it.  If you need a space for temporary or slightly more permanent storage of a file, then look into isolated storage.

Comment: Can/Should we store compact DB file to isolated storage? because we will need directory path for connection string.